# File attachment extension validation?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, infopath, designer-workflow, custom-list

Is there a way to only allow certain file extensions to be attached? I recently added an attachment download button in the body of an automatic email, but it only works for one attachment name or a zip file, so I want to force all attachments to be of the '.zip' extension. Is this possible via SharePoint Designer or InfoPath Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you had known, if you are designing a **browser-compatible form** template, you won't be able to specify which file types are allowed in the file attachment control.

In other words, if you create an InfoPath form using **Blank Form (InfoPath Fillter) template**, you will have that checkbox.

[image]

If you’re using InfoPath browser forms, then this option is not available and you’ll have to [programmatically restrict file types for InfoPath attachments.](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2009/programmatically-restrict-file-types-in-infopath-browser-forms.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an infopath form and use a `FileAttachment` control.

1. Double-click the file attachment control.
2. Click the Data tab.
3. Under Validation and Rules, select the `Allow the user to attach only the following file types` check box, and then, in the box, type the file extensions for the file types that you want to allow.

Comment: Thanks for answering Amal. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but when I double click on the attachment control and try to go to the data tab, everything is greyed out. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Is the form browser enabled?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a newbie at this. Where can I verify that it is enabled?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Specify-the-compatibility-settings-for-a-form-template-dfbcca29-ddb3-4aeb-8a57-d9dbb2e1a660

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding right, the real issue is files do not download correctly in your automatic emails. I will attempt to address the underlying issue and see if that helps you.

To force a file to download, use the following for the link:

```
https://[sitecollection].sharepoint.com/[siteurl]/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=[fileurl]
```

Replace the items in [ ], and use the full URL in [fileurl] and that should fix your underlying issue.